# Good strategy for using git to collaborate with a designer on a ruby on rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I am developing a Ruby on Rails app, and am working with a designer who is not very experienced with rails or with git.  I'm new to using git on a team, but I've used it on my own projects for a while.

What is the easiest way to manage allowing the designer to make the CSS/view edits and push the changes to our git repo, while also being able to review and approve the changes?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably not a good question for SO. Anyway, for review process, I recommend you to use `forks` and `pull-requests`, both supported by GitHub and Bitbucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my team, we use [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for providing a VM that runs the same everywhere. It requires a bit of configuration before it works properly.

We use Github along with [Hub](https://hub.github.com/) to create easy pull-requests. The requests can then be reviewed and merged with the GUI provided on Github website.

The process is then as following:

1. Connect to the VM
2. Create a feature branch with git checkout -b new-branch (from UTD master)
3. Commit and push your code
4. Create the pull-request with hub pull-request [options]
5. Get the code reviewed and merged on Github

To make it easier, you can add whichever git GUI to the process, but I find the command-line to be extremely efficient and it requires little knowledge for the process you seek.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/), which you can use to package up an easy-to-run version of the application, combined with a [Git GUI client](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) makes it a lot easier for a non-programmer designer to work on your project.